# Excel 2013 Format Hyperlinks

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-2013

I'm working with Excel 2013. And I need to style ALL of the Hyperlinks in my workbook.

In Word, I can just select - for example Heading 1 - and modify it. This makes all Heading 1 texts same.

But I couldn't do it with Excel 2013. How to format all of the Hyperlinks (and more can be added later) easily? In all sheets, in all cells, wherever they are in the workbook.

Comment: Have you checked this, if it's any help? http://superuser.com/questions/30814/hyperlink-font-in-excel-always-changes-to-the-default-font-face-size

Comment: Yes. Maybe I'm blind but I can't find any "Hyperlink style" so couldn't use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Hyperlink Style** is on the same row as **Calculation** and **Check Cell**

[image: pic]

.

Just right-click it and pick *Modify...*

You could also use a small macro like:

```
Sub HyperBold()
    ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Hyperlink").Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

If you do this often.

Comment: cool and easy. thanks for your reply. can we do it with "conditional formatting"?

Comment: details? you mean condition details? if yes, nothing. "if a cell contains URL (or formatted as URL), I don't know make it's color red"